# Android studio:3.2.1:Gradle synchronization failed

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application

Gradle synchronization failed. I've tried so many solution but sometimes it shows "connection time out " and sometimes shows "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editting, debugging) will not work properly".

Software specifications are:

- Android studio version: 3.2.1
- Gradle version: 4.6
- Android plugin version: 3.2.1

Images related to the problem are:
[image]

Comment: Please upload the project level `build.gradle` file. Through the image provided, I can see that there is problem with the file(there is problem with the `classpath`)

Comment: I think you forgot to add `google()`  in the `repositories` section of the project level `build.gradle` file

Comment: I've two build.gradle file..which one should I upload?

Comment: how to add Google() in the repositories section?could you please give any image or direction?

Comment: Please paste entire build.gradle file

Comment: Like this in your project level build.gradle: buildscript {
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

Comment: buildscript{  repositories{ Google() jcenter()} dependencies{classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'}} allprojects{repositories{google() jcenter()}} task clean(type:Delete){delete rootProject.buildDir}

Comment: Error:unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In gradle.properties(C:\Users\pcname\  .gradle\gradle.properties) there were some proxy setup commands.After removing those commands and sync again solved my problem.Thank You All

Answer (score 0):

Try these and see if it fixes the problem:

- **If** *your country is included in sanction*, then you can not use Gradle and **you must change your IP address to another country**. You can simply use a **proxy**.

  **Else if** your country is OK with that, you should check your `gradle.properties` (Both global and local) and see if it has proxy enabled or not. If it has proxy enabled, clear the proxy information.
- Make sure you have added `google()` in all of your `repositories` block, and it is above `jcenter()`.
- Use a different version and see if anything changes (In my case `28.0.0` had bugs and i had to downgrade all support versions to `28.0.0-alpha1`)
- Do `invalidate the cache and restart` from `File` menu.
- Clear `.gradle` folder from `C:/Users/YourName/` path and start android studio and sync again.

Answer (score 0):

If your country is included in sanction, then you can not use Gradle and you must change your IP address to another country. You can simply use a proxy.
For example:
You can use psiphone proxy, go to setting-> proxy setting-> and set port and ip address[follow this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fWqp.jpg)
and psiphone setting like this image:
[psiphone setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw9Ie.jpg)

And sync your gradle.

Answer (score 0):

try it and build your project. In Android Studio, Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle . Uncheck Offline work